# Apache module for generating a RFC 4122 compliant uuid

Tags: apache

We are looking to replace our current unique_id module in apache http srver with something that will be able to generate a uuid that is RFC 4122 compliant. If anybody has done something like this already please help us with links/steps. Thanks!